# Convert fulltime to minutes C#

Tags: datetime, c#-4.0, time

I need convert GMT time 14:21:34 to minute (14*60+21=861 minutes)

I know there is a inbuilt function which convert min to HH:MM

Use `TimeSpan.FromMinutes`:

```
var result = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1815);
```

Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: TimeSpan.TotalMinutes - btw. you should try pressing F1 on class Names to see their properties.

Answer (score 1):

Two options to get to a `TimeSpan`:

1) Parse it as a `DateTime` (specifying a format), then use `DateTime.TimeOfDay` to get a `TimeSpan`

```
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
        "14:21:34",
        @"HH\:mm\:ss",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var ts = dt.TimeOfDay;
```

I like this option as it sounds like the value you've got is *meant* to be a time of day.

2) Parse it as a `TimeSpan`:

```
    var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(
        "14:21:34",
        @"hh\:mm\:ss",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Once you have a `TimeSpan`, use `TotalMinutes` (which returns a `double`) to get the number of minutes. For example:

```
Console.WriteLine((int) ts.TotalMinutes); // 861
```